# Bootstrap carousel indicators

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel  I want to do `border-radius` in indicators

added code to style.css but can not change style

```
.carousel-indicators li {
width: 11px!important;
height: 5px!important;
border-radius: 2.5px !important;
background-color: #ffffff!important;
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

why is not it changing how to change , can you help me?

https://i.hizliresim.com/WX4qrE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replicating your issue [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMaNqL), but I could change the indicators style without any trouble.

Is your `style.css` file properly [linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)? Such as: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css">`.

Also, you should avoid using `!important` and try looking for other ways to increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem will be as follows

border-top and border-bottom 0px

[image]